# Unable to change background color of the preview from data of custom struct in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile, background

I'm learning Swift and SwiftUI following to [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/creating-a-card-view). The background color of the preview not changed as expected.

## My code

The `Theme.swift`:

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum Theme: String {
    // ...others
    case yellow

    var accentColor: Color {
        switch self {
        case /* ...others */ .yellow: return .black // <-- Declare the yellow key for accent color
        case .indigo, .magenta, .navy, .oxblood, .purple: return .white
        }
    }
    var mainColor: Color {
        Color(rawValue)
    }
}
```

The `DailyScrum.swift`:

```swift
import Foundation

struct DailyScrum {
    var title: String
    var attendees: [String]
    var lengthInMinutes: Int
    var theme: Theme
}

extension DailyScrum {
    static let sampleData: [DailyScrum] =
    [
        DailyScrum(title: "Design",
                   attendees: ["Cathy", "Daisy", "Simon", "Jonathan"],
                   lengthInMinutes: 10,
                   theme: .yellow), // <-- assign yellow to the first item's theme which referred to the `Theme.swift`
        // others
    ]
}
```

The `CardView.swift`:

```swift
import SwiftUI


struct CardView: View {
    let scrum: DailyScrum
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}


struct CardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var scrum = DailyScrum.sampleData[0] // <-- get first item
    static var previews: some View {
        CardView(scrum: scrum)
            .background(scrum.theme.mainColor) // <-- get the mainColor of the first item
    }
}
```

And what I received in the preview:
[preview of the CardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ginI.png), the background yellow is supposed to appear, but it not.

[Expected Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Sk6.png)

I've tried to change the `scrum.theme.mainColor` to `.yellow` or `scrum.theme.accentColor`, it works. I'm not sure what's the problem here.

My Xcode version is 15, and Swift is 5.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug views like that:

```
struct CardView: View {
    let scrum: DailyScrum
    var body: some View {
      Self._printChanges()
      return Text("Hello, World!")
          .background(scrum.theme.mainColor)
    }
}
```

What I got in console is:

> No color named 'yellow' found in asset catalog for main bundle
> (/Users/______/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews/Simulator
> Devices/id/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/id/Test.app)

Comment: Thanks for the log, I just found out that the Color(rawValue) is not work as expected and it not function like I thought. I fix by make the the `mainColor` same as `accentColor` and it works correctly. I don't know why it's in the tutorial, maybe it works for older version.

Comment: Oh god, the assets, another found out, looks like it not included in the tutorial. Here is how to solve it with the original code: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698144

Just add the assets in the resources.

Comment: Cool, glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are no issues with the code, so please try restarting Xcode, or reloading the Preview with ⌘+⌥+p.

Also, the code below should yield the same results as ExpectedPreview. How about copying this and proceeding with the tutorial?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    let scrum: DailyScrum
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}


struct CardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var scrum = DailyScrum.sampleData[0] // <-- get first item
    static var previews: some View {
        CardView(scrum: scrum)
            .background(scrum.theme.mainColor) // <-- get the mainColor of the first item
    }
}
```

```swift
import Foundation

struct DailyScrum {
    var title: String
    var attendees: [String]
    var lengthInMinutes: Int
    var theme: Theme
}

extension DailyScrum {
    static let sampleData: [DailyScrum] =
    [
        DailyScrum(title: "Design",
                   attendees: ["Cathy", "Daisy", "Simon", "Jonathan"],
                   lengthInMinutes: 10,
                   theme: .yellow), // <-- assign yellow to the first item's theme which referred to the `Theme.swift`
        // others
    ]
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum Theme: String {
    case indigo
    case magenta
    case navy
    case oxblood
    case purple
    case yellow
    
    var accentColor: Color {
        switch self {
        case /* ...others */ .yellow: return .black // <-- Declare the yellow key for accent color
        case .indigo, .magenta, .navy, .oxblood, .purple: return .white
        }
    }
    var mainColor: Color {
        Color(rawValue)
    }
}
```